# Are old backups still kept in Time Machine after excluding some folders?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, time-machine

After Time Machine is running for a year or so, I exclude some folders like `~/Downloads` with the hope to save some disk space on the Time Machine external drive.

- Will the old files (such as those in `~/Downloads`) still kept in TM backup?
- Will disk space be saved on the Time machine external drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old copies stay on the Time Machine backup drive until such time as the date-time for a particular 'snapshot' gets rolled off the drive (deleted) due to TM making space for new backups as the TM drive fills up.

Excluding a folder simply stops it being backed up in future runs.